# h:outputText value to align center

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I was trying to align center the value of h:outputText tag which is surrounded by div tag. I found out that example 1) meets my goal however I was hoping to use css class to meet the need but I've not been successful. Example 2) is what I have tried which failed.

```
Example 1)
<div align="center">
    <h:outputText value="Have a blessed day!" />
</div>

Example 2)
<div class="header">
    <h:outputText value="Have a blessed day!" /.
</div>

In css file
.header {
    align: center;
 }
// tried also text-align
.header {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

[update]
I'm sorry. It was a false alarm. Indeed text-align worked. The browser I was using, IE 10, displayed cached data so I was misled.

Answer (score 5):

`style="display: block; width:100%; text-align:center;"`

works with me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve your requirement

```
<div class="container">
<div class="center">
  <h:outputText value="Have a blessed day!" />
</div>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: block` to its style, and then you can use the `margin: 0 auto` to centralize it.

```
   <h:outputText style="display: block; margin: 0 auto" value="Have a blessed day!"/>
```

Or if you want to use a class:

```
    <h:outputText styleClass="cls" value="Have a blessed day!"/>
    .cls {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use div, You can put it inside the div and set the text direction of the div tag. ;

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p:outputLabel value="xxx"/></div>
```